# Android SharedPreferences value not update in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-broadcastreceiver

I create a SharedPreferences called ALARM with a map called ("alarm",boolean), ("alarm",boolean)'s boolean value changed time to time in MainActivity, and received in a BroadcastReceiver.

The problem is: when I change the value in MainActivity time to time, BroadcastReceiver only change once. What's wrong with my code?

In below code, the start() align to a button, when clicked, change boolean to true. I can see a true value received in the BroadcastReceiver as well. But then I click the stop(), boolean change to false in MainActivity, **but still see a true value received in BroadcastReceiver.**

If I click stop() first, then I always see false value in BroadcastReceiver.(even I click start() many time)

Thanks.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences ALARM;
SharedPreferences.Editor editorALARM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ALARM = getSharedPreferences("ALARM", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editorALARM = ALARM.edit();

}

// start data service
public void start(View view) {
    editorALARM.putBoolean("alarm", true).apply();
    Log.e("start",""+ALARM.getBoolean("alarm", false));

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("xxx.ALARM");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}

// stop data service
public void stop(View view) {
    editorALARM.putBoolean("alarm", false).apply();
    Log.e("stop",""+ALARM.getBoolean("alarm", true));

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("xxx.ALARM");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

}

}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences ALARM;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ALARM = context.getSharedPreferences("ALARM", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Log.e("actual",""+ALARM.getBoolean("alarm", false));

}
}
```

Comment: apply() works in async way, try commit() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the **android: process =":remote"** in manifests.xml, after remove it. I got correct boolean.

Comment: Just curious to know, how does mentioning ":remote" impact save behavior of SharedPreferences?

Comment: After google, I think it related to w/ :remote = work thread, and w/o = UI thread.

Comment: Thanks! This completely makes sense as SharedPreferences can only be updated through UI thread. However, in threads other than UI, I would expect the app crash.

Comment: crash would be better. Unfortunately, nothing happened on non-UI threads. This could cause the debug work more complicate.

Answer (score 0):

replace-

```
editorALARM.putBoolean("alarm", true).apply();
```

with-

```
editorALARM.putBoolean("alarm", true).commit();
```

will work for you